# How to open my android app when a user clicks a link in facebook or some app and display that link in my android app?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, intentfilter

I've already added intent filters in the manifest that will open the app when a link is clicked. When I tap a link a chooser shows my app along a browser. It works fine but I wan't to get the link that tapped before my app is launched. Extra messages in the intent doesn't seem to contain them.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to use other third party services to achieve this functionality on your app.

have a look in http://mobiledeeplinking.org/

Comment: What I want is to open the app whenever any html link is tapped and display it in a textview in my app.